# Bulls and Cows game in C++ having trouble with Cows

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to get a bulls and cows game to work. "Bulls and Cows" is a game where a secret number is generated and you try to guess it.

- A 'bull' represents when you have guessed the correct number in the right place;
- A cow is a correct number but in the wrong place.

i.e.: code 0123 with a guess of 0245 has 1 bull (the zero) and 1 cow as there IS a two but not in that position.

My game is only using 1 and 0 but is nine digits long. Using the below `for` loop the bulls are nice and tidy but i cannot get the cows to work. Either i get a ridiculous answer like "36/9 cows" or it just breaks.

The idea idea behind that code is that if the unmatched (not a bull) pairs can be separated into which are 1 and which are 0, then the smaller of the two groups, when doubled, would be the total of the cows, accounting for both 1 and 0 while discarding the remainder non-bull-or-cow-numbers.

```
int bull = 0, cow = 0;
//checking bull or cow
for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < guess.size(); j++)
    {
        if (guess[i] == n[j] && j == i)         //correct num in right position
            bull++;
        }
    }
    // finding and seperating cows
    int cow1 = 0, cow0 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < guess.size(); j++)
        {
            if (guess[i] == n[j] && i != j && i == 1)          
                cow1++;
            if (guess[i] == n[j] && i != j && i == 0)
                cow0++;
        }
    }
    if (cow0 < cow1)
        cow = cow0;
    else if (cow1 < cow0)
        cow = cow1;
    cow = cow * 2;

    cout << "You have " << bull << "/9 bulls" << endl << "And " << cow << "/9 cows" << endl;
```

Comment: Your conditions inside the loops kind of makes no sense. For example, why have two loops for counting bulls, when one is enough and you check e.g. `guess[i] == n[i]`. Similar with the second loop, where you don't really need the outer loop over `i` at all, since in the condition you hardcode the checks to be only for `guess[0]` and `guess[1]`.

Comment: *"my game is only using 1 and 0 but is nine digits long"* Hmm. Usually one of the preconditions in the Bulls and Cows game is that, in the secret number, all digits are distinct. It's not quite clear how to count cows if a digit may appear more than once (if the secret is `1123` and I guess `1561`, is it one, two or three cows?). But if you only have two digits and 9 positions, there's no way to avoid repetitions.

Comment: i know, but this was what i was assigned. the only way i can think of overcoming this is to have a way of only counting the numbers once

Comment: some programmer dude: im new to this (and as the evaluation of this module will attest, my tutor is less than useless) i dont know what that means

Comment: Use smaller test cases (start with two-digit sequences) and work through your solution on paper before writing a bunch of code.

Comment: To begin with, you ar e missing a close bracket before you find the cows. I'm guessing this was an error when you posted, but anyway I'm leaving as is.

Comment: if anyone has a better code for this, please share! re-write it completely if you must, i just need it working

Comment: I'll write a rough draft as a suggestion. You try and complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thanks for the help but i went another way.
if anyone else needs an answer to this:

//checking bull or cow
                        for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); ++i)
                        {
                            if (guess[i] == n[i])         //correct n`enter code here`um in right position
                                bull++;
                        }
                        // finding and seperating cows
                        int cow1 = 0, cow0 = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); ++i)
                        {
                            if (guess[i] != n[i])
                            {
                                if (guess[i] == 1)
                                    cow1++;
                                else
                                    cow0++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (cow0 < cow1)
                        {
                            cow = cow0;
                        }
                        else
                            cow = cow1;
                        cow = cow * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a question: since your game only works with 0s and 1s, isn't the following true?

1. If a 0 is not a bull and the solution contains at least one 0, then it must be a cow;
2. If a 1 is not a bull and the solution contains at least one 1, then it must be a cow.

This could give you a much simpler solution.

Anyway, let's think of a more general case where you are not limited to 1s and 0s.

Start iterating on the guesses:

```
int bulls = 0;
int cows = 0;
```

For each guess, check if it is a bull. If it is, then increment the number of bulls. Otherwise, check if it is a cow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); i++) {
    if (isBull(guess, n, i)) {
        bulss++;
    }
    else if (isCow(guess, n, i)) {
        cows++;
    }
}
```

Here's what your function `isBull` should look like (I'm guessing `guess` should be of type `std::vector<int>`, but I'm not so sure about `n`; since you didn't make it explicit, I'll just put something geneirc)

```
int isBull(<datatype> guess, <dataype> solution, int pos) {
    return guess[pos] == solution[pos];
}
```

The `isCow()` should have similar parameters. What it should do is simply check for all positions in `solution` if the value in `guess[pos]` appears. It will probably involve something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SOMETHING; i++) {
    if (i != pos && guess[pos] == solution[i]) {
        DO SOMETHING;
    }
}
```

I hope you can understand where I'm trying to go with this. I really don't want to spoil your fun/learning process, so I'll leave the "DO SOMETHING" for you to complete. But if you have questions, just drop a comment and I'll try to answer.

One thing that I'd like to remark: only verify if a position in the guess is a cow if you are sure it's not a bull. it will really simplify your thinking process.